# RobotFramework: How to convert date to lose leading zeros from single digit days

Tags: robotframework, date-format

See below. From checking dateformats, the %d should work but doesnt seem to - see output.

```
Log to console  Completion Date ${completion_date}
${date_to_search_for}=  Convert Date  ${completion_date}  date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S.%f  result_format=%d %b %Y 00:00:00  exclude_millis=True
Log to console  Completion Date ${date_to_search_for}
```

Outputs for  ${completion_date}

```
Completion Date 2017-07-01 08:37:13.656083
```

Outputs for ${date_to_search_for}

```
Completion Date 01 Jul 2017 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the documentation `%d`works exactly as described in the example in the documentation for a [Custom Timestamp](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Custom%20timestamp).

For your desired effect please have a look at the [Python datetime](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Python%20datetime) example:

```
${datetime} =   Convert Date    2014-06-11 10:07:42.123 datetime
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.year}      2014   
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.month}         6  
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.day}           11 
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.hour}      10 
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.minute}        7  
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.second}        42 
Should Be Equal As Integers    ${datetime.microsecond}  123000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_date = datetime.date(2005, 7, 14)
string_date = a_date.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y")
Replace "-" with "#" if using Windows

print(string_date)
```

OUTPUT

```
7/14/2005
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).